# How to create .net 1.1 web method to meet the request and response?

Tags: .net, xml, web-services

Please let me know how to create .net 1.1 web method to meet the below request and response. Thanks in advance.

```
//Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.playtech.com/Services/PTPaymentMethod/Redirect" xmlns:ns2="http://www.playtech.com/Services/PTPaymentMethod"> 
    <env:Header> 
        <ns1:DepositAuthenticationHeaders> 
            <ns2:ApiVersion>1.0</ns2:ApiVersion> 
            <ns2:Credentials> 
                <ns2:MerchantId>Playtech123</ns2:MerchantId> 
                <ns2:MerchantPassword>*****</ns2:MerchantPassword>                                             
                <ns2:Credential1>juur</ns2:Credential1> 
                <ns2:Credential2>ETC</ns2:Credential2> 
            </ns2:Credentials>     
           <ns1:SessionToken>D7BE2D3556A4891B15F8C526154A9DFB</ns1:SessionToken>   
        </ns1:DepositAuthenticationHeaders> 
    </env:Header> 
    <env:Body> 
        <ns1:DepositRequest> 
            <ns1:TransactionId>2-MP-1653261</ns1:TransactionId> 
            <ns1:Amount> 
                <ns2:Amount>1</ns2:Amount> 
                <ns2:Currency>USD</ns2:Currency> 
            </ns1:Amount> 
            <ns1:AccountInfo> 
                <ns2:Field1> 
                    <ns2:Name>Accountid</ns1:Name> 
                    <ns2:Value>12345</ns1:Value> 
                </ns2:Field1> 
                <ns2:Field2> 
                    <ns2:Name>User Name</ns1:Name> 
                    <ns2:Value>John Smith</ns1:Value> 
                </ns2:Field2> 
             </ns1:AccountInfo> 
        </ns1:DepositRequest> 
    </env:Body> 
</env:Envelope>

//Response
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://www.playtech.com/Services/PTPaymentMethod" xmlns:ns2="http://www.playtech.com/Services/PTPaymentMethod/Redirect"> 
    <env:Header>
        <ns2:DepositHeaders> 
            <ns1:ApiVersion>1.0</ns1:ApiVersion>          
           <ns2:SessionToken>D7BE2D3556A4891B15F8C526154A9DFB</ns2:SessionToken>   
        </ns2:DepositHeaders> 
    </env:Header> 
    <env:Body> 
        <ns2:DepositAuthenticationResponse>   
            <ns2:RedirectUrl>https://cashier1.umscasinohf.ptec</ns2:RedirectUrl>   
            <ns2:Status>APPROVED</ns2:Status> 
        </ns2:DepositAuthenticationResponse> 
    </env:Body> 
</env:Envelope>
```

That's it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow isn't a coding service

Comment: .NET Framework 1.1? It has been long dead. Buy a modern book to study latest ASP.NET please.